# AngularJs component based architecture using for kendo grid

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid, components

I'm very new to angular , i know little basic of angular only.

I'm trying to integrate kendo ui grid in my view using angular component.

**My Angular Component :**

```
class GetAllPostController{

    constructor(API, ToastService){
        'ngInject';

        this.API = API;
        this.ToastService = ToastService;
    }

   submit(){
      var data = {
        name: this.name,
        topic: this.topic
      };

       this.API.all('posts').post(data).then((response) => {
         this.ToastService.show('Post added successfully');
       });
    }

    test(){
      alert('');
      this.gridOptions = {
            sortable: true,
            selectable: true,
            dataSource: [
              { text: "Foo", id: 1 },
              { text: "Bar", id: 2 },
              { text: "Baz", id: 3 }
            ],
            columns: [
              { field: "text", title: "Text" }
            ]
          };

    }
}

export const GetAllPostComponent = {
    templateUrl: './views/app/components/get_all_post/get_all_post.component.html',
    controller: GetAllPostController,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindings: {},

}
```

**My View :**

```
<div kendo-grid k-options="gridOptions" k-ng-delay="gridOptions" ng-init="vm.test()"></div>
```

But it's now working. Any one please help ?

And please explain how to use scope inside componenet and view?

I'm using [Laravel Angular Material](https://laravel-angular.readme.io/docs/generators-intro)

Comment: i suggest you to implement kendo inside the angular module..

Comment: @ChathuraHettiarachchi... I don't know about how to do it

Comment: could you please explain your question with more details...  i know how to integrate external frameworks with angular..

Comment: @ChathuraHettiarachchi. I'm using angular with laravel framework. I'm trying to use kendo grid in my angular view page. The page is load using angular component.Inside the component i'm trying to access kendo grid options.But i don't how to use kendo inside ...

Answer (score 0):

suppose u going to implement kendo inside this div

```
<div ng-controller="myController">

</div>
```

The script part

```
<script>
  angular.controller('myController',['$scope',function($scope){

       $scope.results=[];
        /* ajax request and result bind to the $scope.results array */

       //here you implement kendo/what ever other framework
      $scope.apply(function(){

         //write kendo functions inside this apply service

          kendo.gridOptions = {
            sortable: true,
            selectable: true,
            dataSource: $scope.result,
            columns: [
              { field: "text", title: "Text" }
            ]
          };

       })
  }])
</script>
```